# Failed to starting the worker process Celery task with Django in debug = False (production)

Tags: django, redis, celery

This is a Celery task for sending email, the funny thing that everything works correctly in `DEBUG = True` mode, but it does not work in production`DEBUG = False`. Running `celery worker -A invoice2 --loglevel = debug` during the send action and in debug mode activated shows the following:

```
 ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-5] Task enviar_documentos[xxx] raised unexpected: TypeError("enviar_documentos_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cliente'",)
```

First the file that starts the send with the delay:

```
from django.conf import settings
from notifications.tasks import send_async_documents

def send_documents (company, client, documents, type, template = "invoice", context = None):
    send_documents = send_documents_async.delay
    send_documents (type = type,
                    company = company.pk,
                    client = client.pk,
                    template = template,
                    context = context)
```

Second, the task:

```
from celery_app import app
@app.task (name = "send_documents")

def enviar_documentos_async (company, client, documents, type = "FacturaVenta", template = "invoice", context = None):
     if not context:
       context = {}
       klass = KLASS.get (type)
       queryset = klass.objects.filter (pk__in = documents)
       em = Empresa.objects.get (pk = company)
       cl = Cliente.objects.get (pk = client)
       .
       .
       return send_email(
           mail_from = "\"{0.name}\"><{0.email}>".format(em),
           mail_to = cl.email,
           type = template,
           context = context,
           attachments = attachments)
```

Third, the sending of the email:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import Context, Template

def send_email(mail_from, mail_to, type, context = None, attachments = None):
   subject = Template(subject.type).render(mail_context) .replace ("\ n", "")
   message = Template(type.body).render(mail_context)
   ...
   msg = EmailMessage (
          subject,
          linebreaks (message),
          mail_from,
          mail_to)
```

Versions apps installed by pip in the virtualenv:

```
   celery 4.3.0

   Django 2.1.1

   django-extensions 2.0.7

   django-filter 2.1.0

   django-oauth-toolkit 1.1.3

   django-redis 4.10.0

   django-redis-cache 2.0.0

   djangorestframework 3.8.2

   redis 3.2.1

   redis-cache 0.1.5

   redis-structures 0.1.7

   kombu 4.5.0
```

On the server Linux-4.9.0-3-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.0 + nginx/1.10.2 + uwsgi 2.0.17.1:

```
Redis server v = 5.0.4 sha = 00000000: 0 malloc = jemalloc-5.1.0 bits = 64
Celery 4.3.0 (rhubarb)
```

A part of Settings.py

```
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname (abspath (__ file__))
SITE_HTDOCS = normpath (join (DJANGO_ROOT, '../htdocs'))
STATIC_ROOT = normpath (join (SITE_HTDOCS, 'static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath (join (SITE_HTDOCS, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
...
# CELERY
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

Answer (score 2):

With Django in production `debug = False`, Celery don't work directly by running: `celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=info`, it's also necessary to initiate the Celery scripts [daemonization](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd)

```
bin/celery worker --help
```

> Embedded Beat Options:
>     -B, --beat            Also run the celery beat periodic task scheduler.
>                           Please note that there must only be one instance of
>                           this service. .. note:: -B is meant to be used for
>                           development purposes. For production environment, you
>                           need to start celery beat separately.

IMPORTANT param: -B `celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=info -B`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call `enviar_documentos_async` function?
Probably a typo where you provide **client** argument (cliente instead of client).

Comment: The code work perfectly, the problem are in the system `celery worker -A theapp --loglevel=debug` need same more configuration

Comment: SOLVED. With Django in production (debug = False), Celery does not work directly by running: celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=info, it is also necessary to initiate the Celery scripts https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd